# Search multiple rows by space

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a search that searches a SQL table by multiple rows. For example:

```
| FirstName | LastName |
|----------------------|
| John      | Doe      |
|----------------------|
```

`SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Users WHERE FirstName LIKE '%inputhere%' OR LastName LIKE '%inputhere%' LIMIT 10`

When I search a full name (e.g. `John Doe`) no results appear because no one row has that value.

I there a way to separate the search query by spaces in order to avoid this?

Comment: Investigate full text indexes.  That is probably the best solution for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what Gordon said, the best solution is to use Full Text indexes. However, You can do it like this:

```
Select * from Users where concat(FirstName, " ", LastName) like "John Doe"
```

You can feel free to turn `"John Doe"` to `"%John Doe%"` or `"John Doe%"`.

Try it here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0042/5/0

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for what you want is full text indexes.  However, you might be able to accomplish what you want with something like this:

```
where concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname) like concat('%', replace($inputhere, ' ', '%'), '%') or
      concat_ws(' ', lastname, firstname) like concat('%', replace($inputhere, ' ', '%'), '%')
```

This is brute force and requires a full table scan for each query (which is okay for small tables).